# Delete files with same file name

Tags: command-line, grep, delete, duplicate

I have a lot of *.srt file in my folder. The thing is I have some same file multiple times with a slightly different name.
Like This:

```
one_piece_001_US.srt
one_piece_SPECIAL_001_US.srt
one_piece_002_US.srt
one_piece_003_US.srt
one_piece_SPECIAL_003_US.srt
one_piece_004_US.srt
one_piece_SPECIAL_004_US.srt
one_piece_005_US.srt
one_piece_006_US.srt
one_piece_007_US.srt
one_piece_SPECIAL_007_US.srt
```

I want to delete every " **one_piece_SPECIAL_*_US.srt** " file using shell.

Comment: Not quite understand the question. What about `rm *_SPECIAL_*.srt` ?

Comment: can you able to understand it now??

Comment: Then do: `rm one_piece_SPECIAL_*_US.srt`

Answer (score 2):

If the special file name follows the format of names in your example you can use

```
rm -i [DVD]_ONE_PIECE_*_SPECIAL_*US.srt
```

`-i` is interactive mode, so that it always asks you if you want to remove the file, so you will need to press `y` 15 times for each special file, so you don't remove a wrong file by accident, if by any chance there is some other file you want to keep that is in the same name format.

If you don't want to be asked for each file, you can put `-f` instead of `-i`

Answer (score 0):

Go through each and every file then search if the file name contains the substring **SPECIAL** in it. If it does. Remove it with rm command.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.srt; do
    if [[ $file =~ .*SPECIAL.* ]]; then
        echo rm $file
    fi
done
```

To Make The above code work... remove ***echo*** in 5<sup>th</sup> line

Comment: This is just `rm *SPECIAL*.srt` -- no loops or regex needed.